# Is there typescript definition for DOM nativeElement?

Tags: angular, typescript-typings, angular2-testing

I am testing an Angular2 component and want to assert nativeElement's property of the component, but there is no typescript definition for it. My test looks like this:

```
beforeEach( () => {
    myComponentFixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    myComponent = myComponentFixture.componentInstance;
});

it('Should display something', fakeAsync(() => {
    myComponentFixture.detectChanges();

    expect(myComponentFixture.nativeElement.textContent).toContain('something');
}));
```

The problem is that after i type `nativeElement.` there is not IntelliSense for it because I think there are no typings for nativeElement. There are more properties which I may want to check like innerHtml, id, etc. This example test may not make sense, but I may test some specific DOM element's properties using `myComponentFixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#myElement')).nativeElement`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to cast. Because of the multi-platform strategy, they didn't specify a specific type for `nativeElement`:

```
(myComponentFixture.nativeElement as HTMLElement)....
```